# CUDALink support-Mathematica 11

Tags: cudalink, gpu, opencllink

Greetings & Salutations,

I have Mathematica 11.0 on a Windows 10(Home) system with a Nvidia GTX1050Ti gpu, **driver version 382.33** and **CUDA version 8.0.61**; I am getting CUDALink is not supported and OpenCLLink not supported.
Is my gpu/cuda/opencl setup supported by Mathematica 11.0; if not what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance

---

Additional information:

```
CUDAQ[]
```

> `False`

```
CUDADriverVersion[]
```

> `Mod[100 Revision Number, 1000]`

```
CUDAResourcesInformation[]
```

> ```
> {{"Name" -> "CUDAResources", "Version" -> "8.0.4.2", 
>   "BuildNumber" -> "", "Qualifier" -> "Win64", 
>   "WolframVersion" -> "8.0.1+", "SystemID" -> {"Windows-x86-64"}, 
>   "Description" -> "{ToolkitVersion -> 4.0, MinimumDriver -> 270.0}", 
>   "Category" -> "", "Creator" -> "", "Publisher" -> "", 
>   "Support" -> "", "Internal" -> False, 
>   "Location" -> 
>    "C:\\Users\\Vector\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Paclets\\\
> Repository\\CUDAResources-Win64-8.0.4.2", "Context" -> {}, 
>   "Enabled" -> True, "Loading" -> Manual, 
>   "Hash" -> "62976eb492c28aa3d0ecf6fcb6ed9013"}}
> ```

```
CUDACCompilers[]
```

> ```
> {{"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
>   "Compiler" -> 
>    CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
>   "CompilerInstallation" -> 
>    "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0", 
>   "CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
>   "Compiler" -> 
>    CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
>   "CompilerInstallation" -> 
>    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0", 
>   "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}
> ```

Comment: Please add the information `CUDADriverVersion[]`, `CUDAInformation[]`, `CUDAResourcesInformation[]`, and `CUDACCompilers[]` return. Does `CUDAQ[]` return `False`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your CUDA paclet is outdated. Updating it with

```
CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]
```

should fix your problems.

---

The output of `CUDAResourcesInformation[]` reveals that you currently have version 8.0.4.2 installed. The latest version of the CUDA Resources is 10.5.0 (based on [its web page](http://www.wolfram.com/CUDA/CUDAResources.html)). If updating via `CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]` fails, you can follow the manual update procedure I outlined in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96737/18476).